# I'm trying to connect to a Google cloud SQL instance from NodeJS with the following code

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
var con = mysql.createPool({
   password:process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_PASSWORD,
   user:process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_USER,
   database :process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_DATABASE,
   //port:3306, 
   //host: 'localhost' 
 socketPath:'/cloudsql/process.env.GOOGLE_INSTANCE_NAME
});
```

Trying to use a socket throws the error ACCESS DENIEL FOR USER ROOT@CLOUDSQL35.125.**** (USING PASSWORD :NO) ,

I can connect from my local machine (using the command line) to Google cloud sql successfully and see my database and tables and use it. 
But when I deployed the app it will be showing access deniel for user in the error log and internal server error in my browser. 
What do I miss?

Comment: do you have the service account configured? You may take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#nodejs)

Comment: You must specify a password (look at the error message). For additional debugging tips: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues